# Why is the electric field between two equally charged conductors zero?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, conductors

Two equally charged conductors of area $A$ and charge $Q$ are placed at a distance $a$ from each other. I want to calculate the electric field caused by the two conductors. I applied gauss law to each of them and got $E=\frac{Q}{A \epsilon_0}$ and that it points in the radial direction for each conductor. However, the solution manual says that the field in the region between the conductors is zero, and that it is $E=\frac{Q}{A \epsilon_0}$ elsewhere.

I don't understand how the results from Gauss law on each conductor results in that the field is zero in the region between the conductors? And why is the field $\frac{Q}{A \epsilon_0}$ in the other regions? This was the result I got for each conductor, how is the total field equal to the field of one conductor?

Also, the charge on the conductors will redistribute itself so that one conductor has positive charge and the other negative charge on the surface where they are facing each other. If the field is zero between the conductors (which I sort of can see if we take a Gaussian surface enclosing the two halfs of the conductors that are close to each other since the enclosed charge will be zero), why does the redistribution of the charge within the conductor not affect how the electric field is elsewhere. I'm thinking that we will have another charge that causes the rest of the field, like $Q/2$?

Sorry if my question is unclear, would really appreciate if someone could explain a bit further where I'm thinking wrong.

Comment: The electric field is a vector, perhaps you should draw a picture of what the electric fields of each plate will look like in the three regions around the plates.

Comment: I did but did not get that they should add to zero, only that the vertical component cancel out each other but not the horizontal

Comment: For a charged plate there is no horizontal component, however you haven't actually specified the geometry of the objects in question. I only have that the expression you give looks like the field of an infinite plate.